# google plus login in ionic returns error 10

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I am using google plus login in ionic application. Login functionality is properly working 4.2, 4.3 android devices. But it returns error:10 in 5+ android versions. For this i am using this plugin 'cordova-plugin-googleplus'. I installed it by Cordova CLI and npm

Here is my code.

```
     window.plugins.googleplus.login(
        {},
        function (user_data) {
          alert(JSON.stringify(user_data));   
        },
        function (msg) {
          alert(msg);
        }
    );
```

I didn't get any working solutions from my search. Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you find a solution for this ?

Answer (score 5):

Give all credits to  [ERROR:10 , what am i missing ??](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus/issues/243)

I spent a couple of hours searching this issue for my ionic 3 application. The mistake I was made is I was using Client ID for Android.

The ionic app should use **Client ID for Web**!

Comment: I spent full day for this error. After read your answer i get solution. thank you so much.

Comment: @user11469878 glad it helps!

Comment: @user11469878. I'm still having this issue.  I deleted my oAuth2 web client and created a new one to no avail.  did you use the variable WEB_APPLICATION_CLIENT_ID= when creating your cordova-plugin-googleplus

Answer (score 2):

After so much troubleshooting, i found the proper solution

Three possibilities are there

1) May be you use the android client id during the install the plugin
-  in this case you should only use the webclient id even though you build for android
- Screenshot attached

2) You should only use DEBUG SHA1  key during build of the debug apk and use PROD SHA1 key during production release apk.

- You can also add both DEBUG and PROD SHA1 key in firebase console. Please find attached screenshot for more info.

[image: Screenshot1]

Debug SHA1 Command : **keytool -exportcert -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -list -v**
   - Make sure  **~/.android/debug.keystore** is default keystore provide by android SDK, no need to change.
 password :  **android**

Release SHA1 Command : **keytool -exportcert -keystore  ~/your-path/playstore-release-sample.keystore -list -v**
   - where ~/your-path/playstore-release-sample.keystore is your keystore which you are using during generate the signed APK

3) You should on pass the webclientID during the google log api not and android client id.

[image]

```
Webclient ID only - Find in attached screenshot
 **'webClientId': '900429691586-.............apps.googleusercontent.com',**

async login() {
    let params;
    if (this.platform.is('android')) {
      params = {
        'webClientId': '900429691586-.............apps.googleusercontent.com',
        'offline': true
      }
    }
    else {
      params = {}
    }
    this.googlePlus.login(params)
      .then((response) => {
        const { idToken, accessToken } = response
        this.onLoginSuccess(idToken, accessToken);
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
        this.globalService.showSimpleAlertMessage('Getting Error :' + JSON.stringify(error), "OK")
      });   }   onLoginSuccess(accessToken, accessSecret) {
    const credential = accessSecret ? firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider
      .credential(accessToken, accessSecret) : firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider
        .credential(accessToken);
    this.firebaseAuth.auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
      .then((response) => {
        this.storage.set("firebaseSuccessResponse", response)
        this.router.navigate(["/home"]);
        this.globalService.hideLoading();
      })   }   onLoginError(err) {
    console.log(err);   }
```

Hope this step resolve your problem permanently

Comment: This should be the correct answer! I was struggling for days and finally manage to solve my issue. I was mixed up with keystore files and SHA1 keys.. thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I create a client id in console developer google (for android).
I assigned the id generated in package.json and I typed ionic state reset to reinstall the plugins

I have to create debug-signing.propoerties and release-signing.propoerties to sign apk

And it solved my problem in my case

Answer (score 0):

Use Existing Debug Keystore Instead of Creating New...

Example : keytool -exportcert -keystore **~/.android/debug.keystore** -list -v -alias androiddebugkey

Default Password Will Be : **android**

For Working Fine / For Windows Just Replace Path of debug.keystore

Thank you :)