# ionic cordova plugin cordova-plugin-googleplus error 10

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-native, google-plus-signin

I am trying to login with google plus but getting the error 10
In my google developer console i'm choosing Web Application as the application type
I have installed cordova plugin google plus with web client id I get from OAuth
I have enabled google+API in developer console and enabled google login in firebase
Still getting error 10

Comment: add your sha1 key in google

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40435615/google-plus-login-in-ionic-returns-error-10

Comment: I'm using a web application in google console. I don't see any option there for sha1 key. SHA1 key comes while creating android application